# AngularJS: changing $rootScope variable doesn't change first selected option in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-rootscope, javascript-inheritance

I have a specific problem which I can't seem to crack.

In html I have following code:

```
<select ng-model="$parent.proizvod"  ng-options="i.id_proizvod as i.proizvod for i in proizvodiServer">
   <option>Select</option>
 </select>
```

And in my controllers:

```
  $rootScope.proizvod = '1';
```

So when the page first loads, the first option is selected. If I change the `$rootScope.proizvod = '1';` to `$rootScope.proizvod = '3';` It will load the third option.

Now, when you select some other value, it will store it in `$rootScope.proizvod`, but later, in some function,  I want to reset that `$rootScope.proizvod` back to '1' and it doesn't seem to be working.

What am I missing here?

P.S. without `$parent.proizvod`, my select doesn't even change the   `$rootScope.proizvod` value.

EDIT: Here's the other fucntion:

```
$rootScope.upisPodataka = function() {
      setTimeout(function () {
      $rootScope.proizvod = '1';
      $scope.$apply();
       }, 2000);
      $state.go('app.podesenost_grilla', {}, {
        reload: true
      });
```

upisPodataka function is called on a click of a button.

Comment: show your "other function"

Comment: It's basically the same as it is in the controller. I've edited the question now.

Comment: Why are you using rootscope for keepin track of a select option? All scopes will inherit that value..Thats bad design. Attach the value to the scope of the controller instead. Also, use $setTimeout instead of using setTimeout and manually triggering the digest loop. The $setTimeout will take care of that for you as its wrapped in an $apply.

Comment: I'm using $rootScope because I use that variable in 2 controllers.

Comment: @MarcusH The Angular service that wraps window.setTimeout is $timeout, see [AngularJS $timeout API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ng-model='$parent.proizvod'` is not guaranteed to update `$rootScope` in all circumstances.

> New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved.
>
> — [AngularJS Wiki - Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

If the `ng-model` sets the value in a child scope. The child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. Read the Wiki.

So the question becomes should it be `$parent.$parent.proizvod`? Or maybe `$parent.$parent.$parent.proizvod`? Do it by trial and error?

A more robust approach is to use the [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to update the variable.

```
<select ng-model="vm.proizvod" ng-change="vm.update()"
        ng-options="i.id_proizvod as i.proizvod for i in proizvodiServer">
   <option>Select</option>
</select>
```

```
vm.update = function () {
    $rootScope.proizvod = vm.proizvod;
    console.log($rootScope.proizvod);
});
```

---

Instead of using `$rootScope`, consider using a [custom service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services) to store the variables.

> ### `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil
>
> Scopes in AngularJS form a hierarchy, prototypically inheriting from a root scope at the top of the tree. Usually this can be ignored, since most views have a controller, and therefore a scope, of their own.
>
> Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to the whole app. For these, you can inject `$rootScope` and set values on it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope, these values will be available to the expressions attached to directives like `ng-show` just like values on your local $scope.
>
> Of course, global state sucks and you should use `$rootScope` sparingly, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put a function on `$rootScope`, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.
>
> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.
>
> [— AngularJS FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

---

### Use $timeout instead of window.setTimeout

```
$rootScope.upisPodataka = function() {
      //setTimeout(function () {
      $timeout(function () {
         $rootScope.proizvod = '1';
         //$scope.$apply();
      }, 2000);
      $state.go('app.podesenost_grilla', {}, {
        reload: true
      });
};
```

The [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout) wraps `windows.setTimeout` and integrates it with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Then `$apply()` is not needed.

In addition, `$timeout.flush()` can be used when testing.

Comment: Seems to work flawlessy! One thing though, I knew about child scopes, so that was the reason I put $parent on it, but it seems that I have not yet fully grasped angular scopes!
Thanks!